# Is it possible to convert this Java code to Jython for a Minecraft Plugin?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jython, minecraft

I was looking at this video to find some information on making Minecraft Plugins. https://youtu.be/r4W4drYdb4Q
All plugins are made with Java. Since I program with Python I was wondering if it is possible to make a Plugin similar to the one seen in the video but with Jython. I am not sure if this is possible but I started trying.

When programming Java most people use Eclipse and there is a button that says "Add external Jar" and that is where you input the spigot jar file. From what I understand I can do that with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("spigot-1.15.2.jar")
```

in Jython. Then there comes the tricky part. How would I go about converting this:
[Code Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYTxT.png)

[Code Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33TSW.png)

From what I thought I needed to do was something like:

```html
from org.bukkit.plugin.java import JavaPlugin

class Main(JavaPlugin):
    def onEnable():
        pass
        #what do I put here?
    def onDisable():
        pass
        #what do I put here?
```

But I don't think I am properly converting the Java code to Jython. What would be the proper way to convert the code from Java to Jython?
Thanks very much!

Comment: It will be way easier for you to learn Java than it will be to get Jython working as a Bukkit plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to interact from your Jython code with a Java class which extends `JavaPlugin`.

For this I suggest you write a thin wrapper *in Java* which then calls your Jython code where you do the heavy lifting in your familiar language. A skeleton of the wrapper could look like this:

```java
package {$GroupName}.{$ArtifactName};

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public final class {$ArtifactName} extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();
        pi.execfile("enable.py"); // enable.py is the Jython file with the enable stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();
        pi.execfile("disable.py"); // enable.py is the Jython file with the disable stuff
    }

}
```

Be aware that instantiating `PythonInterpreter` is rather slow, so you'd be better off with a pattern where you do this only once. Plus then you can share data between `enable` and  `disable`!

For more details and other options (like having the Jython stuff in one file and calling into it via `pi.exec`) look at [Chapter 10: Jython and Java Integration](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JythonAndJavaIntegration/#using-jython-within-java-applications) in the Jython Book.

Also keep in mind when coding away: Jython is only Python 2.7!!!